# IJSInProcessRuntime Blazor Wasm to MAUI

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm application I would like to port to Blazor MAUI. In many of the pages we are using IJSInProcessRuntime because we found its faster to pass large chunks of data to javascript which we are using in order to render grids in third party components.

But now, as far as I understand IJSInProcessRuntime is not available in MAUI and not even planned to be.

What is reasonable way forward? Can I register the service somehow to fallback on other JSRuntime if its not available?

I am registering the service like this

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => (IJSInProcessRuntime)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>());
```

then we inject it on many pages like this

```
@inject IJSInProcessRuntime JSInProcessRuntime
```

Upon page load this error shows up

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Services.WebViewJSRuntime' to type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSInProcessRuntime'.'
```

Comment: Just inject IJSRuntime. You will get the correct interop implementation wherever you use your components. If you need access to the specific methods on the IJSInProcessRuntime, you can test for `if (injectedJSRuntime is IJSInProcessRuntime inProcessJS) ...` and then use inProcessJS to acces the sync methods

Comment: Thanks for comment! How can I inject IJSRuntime without changing all my calls to IJSInProcessRuntime? Everywhere in the codebase we have calls like this: 
JSInProcessRuntime.Invoke<object>(....

Comment: You can't do it without refactoring because you wrote it dependent on the InProcess implementation.

Comment: Any update regarding this in .NET 7 or .NET 8 or is it still refactoring that is needed in order to use this?

Comment: No, there is unlikely to ever be an update that does this